# Periodic call in android every 90 seconds, even when app is closed

Tags: android, performance

The requirement is to record the position every 90 seconds and write it to database(sqlite) and if network is available then call an api, even if the app is closed.
Which will be the best possible way to achieve this?
Should I start an intent service? Or I should go with an alarm Manager. I have read somewhere that alarm manager should only be used if the duration is more than 10 minutes.

Comment: use started service

Comment: You could try using a normal Service and Handler.
Where the handler performs the necessary tasks every 90 seconds and the handler could be inside the Service which will run in the background if it is started with a "START_STICKY" flag;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use AlarmManager since it can be run even Device is asleep.
Note that, for API v > 19, the alarm delivery is inexact and you have to use setExact api to achieve that . 
See

> Note: Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is treated as inexact: the alarm will not be delivered before this time, but may be deferred and delivered some time later. The OS will use this policy in order to "batch" alarms together across the entire system, minimizing the number of times the device needs to "wake up" and minimizing battery use. In general, alarms scheduled in the near future will not be deferred as long as alarms scheduled far in the future.
>   With the new batching policy, delivery ordering guarantees are not as strong as they were previously. If the application sets multiple alarms, it is possible that these alarms' actual delivery ordering may not match the order of their requested delivery times. If your application has strong ordering requirements there are other APIs that you can use to get the necessary behavior; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent).

Answer (score 1):

Alarm Manager would be the ideal choice for your situation. Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep, but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.
So, you can use this to run your job in 90 seconds interval. It may break the interval only first time after the device is rebooted.

Answer (score 1):

Another way I found out was using the Firebase job dispatcher. That is the best option for devices running on marshmallow or further. It is easy to integrate and customizable.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Answer (score 0):

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running
>   operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

> The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your
>   application code run at a specific time, even if your application is
>   not currently running.
>   The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm
>   receiver's onReceive() method is executing. This guarantees that the
>   phone will not sleep until you have finished handling the broadcast.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Go with the service.

Answer (score 0):

You go with Intent service and Broadcastreceiver componenst, because those components only listen continuously, even if you close the Application.

And you want to get something evry 90 seconds, so use Alarm Manager.

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) (context)
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, YourAlarmReceuver.class);

        //alarmIntent.putExtra("syncData", favoritesArrayList);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), 90*1000, pendingIntent);
```

Your Receiver class Like this

```
public class SyncAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      Intent stIntent = new Intent(context,
                    YourService.class);
        context.startService(stIntent);

       }
```

And Your Intent Service Class like this

```
public class DataSyncService extends IntentService {


    public DataSyncService() {
        super(DataSyncService.class.getName());
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

         //write your logic here 
        // get the location and update the database
    }

}
```

You should instantiate the alarm manager boot completed also.

Comment: This will not work reliably. A `WakeLock` is not provided for the `Service`, so the device can go back to sleep before it could get executed.

Comment: Alarm Manager should work, even the device in sleep mode. But  if the device restarted, then it losses the all alarms, for this we need instantiates the alarm manager when boot completed.

Comment: Yes, the `AlarmManager` will work, since a `WakeLock` is guaranteed during `onReceive()`, but the device can go back to sleep right after `onReceive()` finished. That's why you have to provide a `WakeLock` for the `Service`, either manually, or by using the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` helper class.

Comment: As @earthw0rmjim said, WakefulBroadcastReceiver should be used here.

Comment: Also, `setInexactRepeating()` is the worst possible choice here. The alarms will not be exact and they will not work with Doze.